# Java API for filtering query in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How can I write a query with a filter as a missing field.
I want to query all records which match that filter for that type in index.

How would I write that? I am using ES 2.1.

```
GET eb_portal_index/part/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "missing": { "field" : "object_desc" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [                        
                    { "missing": { "field": "object_desc" } }
                ]
            }
        }
     }
 }
}
```